# ElasticSearch/Lucene not_analyzed: difference from relational databases

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, lucene, relational-database

I'm new to ElasticSearch so some indexing aspects are unclear. I wonder if it would be more efficient than relational database in following case.

There is a document schema containing many simple string and numeric fields. The fields set is well known, so can be represented as a relational table as well. String values are identifiers so the analyzer is turned off. The search is made by full-value match for strings and numeric comparison (equal, less, greater) for numbers. Assume the fields count is large, lets say 200.

Search criteria may include any combination of fields.

I don't know exactly how the ES performs search of not_analyzed fields but guess there is no big difference from the relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

The relative performance (relational vs. ES) is going to depend on the size of your data and complexity of your queries.

Elasticsearch is designed for query performance - so *generally* you should find ES to be faster and more scalable than relational.

However you'll need to run tests with your data queries to confirm though.

Comment: _Search criteria may include any combination of fields._ I mean that query complexity depends on user choice, for example `field1='abcd' and field2=3 and field22>10 and (field30='aaa' or field100<20)`. Number of documents is something about 50000.

Comment: The query you've supplied should be fine in ES.  50k documents is a small number for ES - you should be able to run this volume of documents on a single PC.